# Force mobile layout inside a div

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using Bootstrap 3, and I have a `div`:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-3">
</div>
```

In a certain situation, I want to display this `div` inside another `div` with a fixed width:

```
<div style="width:240px;">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-3">
    </div>
</div>
```

Although the width is `240px` it still uses `col-lg-3` for the grid. I know if I use an `iframe`, it will pick the `col-xs-12` class, and there is no need for the outer `div`.

I wonder if there is anyway to force using `col-xs-12` in this situation?

Comment: This would require something like [Element Queries](http://responsiveimagescg.github.io/eq-usecases/), which don't yet exist. You're probably going to need to use JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

If you know when the certain situations appear, can't you just remove the "col-lg-3" class from those specific divs?

Comment: I can. But I am looking for a better (and cleaner) way.